# JS+IE9 (default security): Redirect automatically to clickonce application

Tags: javascript, clickonce, internet-explorer-9

I need to be able to redirect from a silverlight application to a clickonce .application. The problem with this is that SL redirects via javascript, and it seems IE9 in its default security settings won't allow it.
Right now I'm stuck redirecting to a page with a "Click here to proceed" link, but it's not really the best. I tried redirecting to the link address automatically, but to no avail.
This would all work if I have my page added as a secure site, but I can't go telling people that they need to do that if they want to use this correctly... If any of you can tell me how to make my page prompt the user to add the site as secure without them having to do so manually, though, I would consider the issue resolved.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end we phased out SL and used a standard aspx (because of this and other issues). Thanks for your time, everyone.